# How can i replace the document path with a value from a text box?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried setting the document path with a value from textbox.
But the app keeps on crashing whenever i try doing it.

```
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document(textDisplay2.getText().toString());
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                Log.d("TAG", document.getString("name")); //Print the name
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: If you log the results of textDisplay2.getText().toString() what does it print?

Comment: It worked when I replaced  textDisplay2.getText().toString() with String.valueOf( textDisplay2.getText()). @AlexMamo

Comment: @surajsuresh29 Good to hear that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document(String.valueOf(textDisplay2.getText());
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document != null && document.exists()) {
            Log.d("TAG", document.getString("name")); //Print the name
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
    }
  }
});
```